# Can't connect to a rust tcp server that is running on replit.com

Tags: rust, tcp, replit

I want to make a chat server between my computer and a server that is running on replit but I can't connect to the replit server (it works when I run the server on my device so the code seems to work)

Here is the server-side code that runs on replit:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::str;
use std::thread;

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut data = [0; 4096];

    loop {
        let len = stream.read(&mut data)?;

        let text = str::from_utf8(&data[..len]).unwrap();
        println!("Received: {}", text);

        println!("What do you want to send: ");
        let mut input = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        stream.write_all(input.as_bytes())?;
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:6969")?;

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream?;
        println!("New connection: {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
        thread::spawn(move || handle_client(stream));
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

And here is the client-side code:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::str;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co:6969")?;

    loop {
        println!("What do you want to send: ");
        let mut input = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        stream.write_all(input.as_bytes())?;

        let mut data = [0; 4096];
        let len = stream.read(&mut data)?;
        let text = str::from_utf8(&data[..len]).unwrap();
        println!("Recieved: {}", text);
    }
}
```

When the server is running on replit and I try to connect to it I get this error:
`Error: Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "Failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution" }`

I tried to change the address from IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co:6969 to:
IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co
https://IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co:6969
http://IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co:6969
https://IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co
http://IncompleteHelpfulServer.smartflow.repl.co
But neither of them worked

I searched if it was even possible and it was also if I try to connect to the address with my browser the replit server gets some info about my browser so I think there is a problem in the client-side code

Can somebody help me fix this?
Thanks for reading

Comment: There is a decent chance that replit does not allow you to host a non-web server. They have some documentation for doing an HTTP server, but other kinds of traffic are not mentioned in the documentation. You may need to run your server on port 80 (the default port for HTTP) and if that is not enough, format messages as HTTP requests. If you want to make a non-web server, you may need to use a different hosting service. For example, this would work fine using the free-tier of AWS.

Comment: Also, this server will not work as-is. `stream.read` makes no guarantees on how much data will be read and just attempts to fill your buffer with what the network buffer has received since the last call. It could receive a full packet, a packet fragment, multiple packets, or a packet might not even fit in the buffer. In non-blocking mode, it may even return no bytes at all. All it guarantees is that bytes will be in order. You may want to try prefixing each message with the message length so you can separate them.

Comment: @Locke I tried 80 and 443 same error so now I will try AWS

Comment: I wasn't free I couldn't sign up

Comment: it provides free tiers for many resources, but is still a professional service. They require billing information so they can charge you if you exceed the free tier limits. For example, if you exceeded more than 15GB of outbound network traffic in a month, each additional GB will cost you around ~10 cents. Assuming you run your server on a free tier EC2 instance and do not exceed this limit, I don't see this costing you anything. However since AWS is a professional service it can be quite confusing and difficult to navigate for beginners so I suggest you find a tutorial first.

Comment: @Locke Sound good but I actually managed to do it with HTTPS with TLS and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with hyper and native-tls with https
S.O to @Locke in the comments